# Aggregate syntax in R

Tags: r

I have the following final output and I want to get the mean of the A variable according to their value using all B and specific value of C. I want to use aggregate, but how can I use R syntax in order to get the desired result:

data

```
A B C   Output   
1 1 1 2.99999999930144
1 1 2 2.99999999930144
1 1 3 0.999999999301437
1 1 4 6.98562985235185e-10
1 1 5 6.98562985235185e-10
3 1 1 2.99999999930144
3 1 2 2.99999999930144
3 1 3 0.999999999301437
3 1 4 6.98562985235185e-10
3 1 5 6.98562985235185e-10
3 2 1 2.00000000069856
3 2 2 6.98559432521506e-10
3 2 3 0.999999999301441
3 2 4 0.999999999301441
3 2 5 6.98559432521506e-10
5 1 1 1.74719003022506
5 1 2 1.74719003022506
5 1 3 0.252809969774944
5 1 4 1.25280996977494
5 1 5 1.25280996977494
5 2 1 1.73354977330464
5 3 3 1.26645022669536
5 3 4 0.266450226695358
5 3 5 0.733549773304642
1 1 1 2.99999999930144
1 1 2 2.99999999930144
1 1 3 0.999999999301437
1 1 4 6.98562985235185e-10
1 1 5 6.98562985235185e-10
1 2 1 2.09563211228669e-09
1 2 2 1.99999999790437
```

I want the mean of A, using all B and specific values of C: I want output which look like the following

```
A  C   mean(output)
1  1
3  1
5  1

A   c  mean(output)
1   2
3   2
5   2
```

I used the following syntax:

```
aggregate(data$output, by = list (data$c), FUN = Mean)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
aggregate(Output~A+C,data = df,FUN = mean,na.rm=T)

   A C       Output
1  1 1 2.000000e+00
2  3 1 2.500000e+00
3  5 1 1.740370e+00
4  1 2 2.666667e+00
5  3 2 1.500000e+00
6  5 2 1.747190e+00
7  1 3 1.000000e+00
8  3 3 1.000000e+00
9  5 3 7.596301e-01
10 1 4 6.985630e-10
11 3 4 5.000000e-01
12 5 4 7.596301e-01
13 1 5 6.985630e-10
14 3 5 6.985612e-10
15 5 5 9.931799e-01
```

Comment: thank you very much, if I want pull out the mean, when c=1, c=2...automatically and separately?

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Do you mean just computing mean when `c==1,c==2`? In that case you could use `aggregate(Output~A+C,data = df[df$C==1|df$C==2,],FUN = mean,na.rm=T)` Let me know if this helped!

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Also you could use `subset` argument from `aggregate()` like this: `aggregate(Output~A+C,data = df,FUN = mean,na.rm=T,subset = c(C==1|C==2))`

Comment: I got this error using  aggregate(Output~A+C,data = df[df$C==1|df$C==2,],FUN = mean,na.rm=T),  Error in df$c : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Try checking the names in your dataframe or the class. Why you got c instead of C? Check the names

Comment: @Thanks, Duck, I will get back to you if I have another problem on this issue..

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Great :)